# Recommended tools for benchmarking Ruby and Perl

Tags: python, ruby, perl

I want to compare the execution time for mathematical equations for different dynamic, interpreted programming languages like Ruby, Perl, and Python.

In Python, there is the convenient `timeit` module, which allows me to time, where I can simply time for, e.g., a least squares fit (`python_lstsqr(x,y)`) via

```
min(timeit.Timer('python_lstsqr(x, y)', 
            'from __main__ import python_lstsqr, x, y')\
                                        .repeat(repeat=3, number=1000))
```

(here the best of 3 repetitions and 1000 loops per repetition)

Are there equivalents in Perl and Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good old `time` ?

For Perl, you can use built-in [`Benchmark`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) or [`Time::Stopwatch`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aStopwatch).

For Ruby, the built-in [`benchmark`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) is good enough.